# Bootstrap 3 - Collapse Navbar and Sub Navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

https://www.bootply.com/t29IadMjRG

I need some help trying to figure out how to collapse a double navbar setup for 1-col or for mobile using bootstrap. Ideally I'd like both navbars to collapse into the same collapsed unified menu.

I've been copying and pasting and editing to try and figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can do it is to create a different navbar for mobiles with your single options.
You can then use visible-xs-block and hidden-xs to show/hide accordingly.